# How to make .MergeShapes behave properly?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Having a tear-hair-out problem with a macro that uses the .MergeShapes command. Sometimes it works fine, and sometimes it results in error (Method 'MergeShapes' of object 'ShapeRange' failed.)

Here is a bare-essentials code snippet, with a commented-out solution that works but slows things down too much:

```
Sub MergeMyShapes(solidShp As Shape, txtShp As Shape, slideIndex As Long)

Dim shpArray() As Variant
Dim shpRange As ShapeRange
Dim currentSlide As Slide
Dim koType As MsoMergeCmd

Set currentSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(slideIndex)
koType = msoMergeIntersect

shpArray(1) = GetShapeNumber(solidShp, slideIndex)
shpArray(2) = GetShapeNumber(txtShp, slideIndex)
Set shpRange = currentSlide.Shapes.Range(shpArray)

'   Adding a 1 second delay before the .MergeShapes fixes the issue, but
'   it's too slow!

 '  Delay 1, True

' This is the line that sometimes crashes
    shpRange.MergeShapes koType, solidShp

End Sub

' This is some re-purposed code that I'm using to delay.

Public Sub Delay(Seconds As Single, Optional DoAppEvents As Boolean)
  Dim TimeNow As Long
  TimeNow = Timer
  Do While Timer < TimeNow + Seconds
    If DoAppEvents = True Then DoEvents
  Loop
End Sub
```

This is driving me nuts because I had hoped to avoid timing issues by using the .MergeShapes method as opposed to an ExecuteMso command.  There seems to be little rhyme or reason behind the crashing; the exact same shapes will sometimes work and sometimes not work depending on mood.

Answer (score 1):

Sleep is a Windows routine that can be used for periods shorter than 1 second. First, declare it:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
```

Then set up error trapping before the problem operation:

```
TryCut1:
  On Error GoTo TooFast1
  'Problem statement goes here
  On Error GoTo 0
```

Then add sleep statements at the end of the module:

```
  Exit Sub
TooFast1:
  Sleep 10
  Resume TryCut1
```

The result is that on an error, the sleep routine waits for just 10 milliseconds and tries again. This way the pause is reduced to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks but this is not resolving the issue.  A hard delay of 1 second resolves the issue most of the time, and a delay of 2 seconds resolves it 100% of the time.  A MsgBox "Break!" command right before the .MergeShapes also fixes it 100% of the time.  But the Sleep method created an infinite loop the first time I tried it, and when I tied the error to a counter (only letting it run 10 or 100 times before just exiting out of the sub), the .MergeShapes command never ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution in case this helps other people -- the Sleep routine that John suggested didn't work (no matter how long the delay was before .MergeShapes, I still got the same error, so without an escape hatch it created an infinite loop), but using his error handling methodology I was able to cut the Delay amount down to the bare minimum.

This section of code now looks like:

```
delayValue = 0.5

TryMerge:
  On Error GoTo TooFast1

  Debug.Print "sleeping " & delayValue & " seconds"
  Delay delayValue, True

  shpRange.MergeShapes koType, solidShp

  On Error GoTo 0

  Debug.Print "Successful merge!"
```

And then at the bottom of the sub:

```
TooFast1:
Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Description

If delayValue > 2 Then
  Exit Sub
Else
  delayValue = delayValue + 0.1
  Resume TryMerge
End If
```

It appears that the .MergeShapes method needs some wait time before running after you've set your ShapeRange.

My Immediate window looks like this after a successful run (they've all been successful so far):

```
sleeping 0.5 seconds
Error: Method 'MergeShapes' of object 'ShapeRange' failed
sleeping 0.6 seconds
Successful merge!
```